# Installation of SQL database on local machine as opposed to Virtual machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, installation, virtual-machine

I have configured Virtual machine to install Sharepoint 2010. The virtual machine is configured as;

a. **OS**: Windows Server 2008 
b. **Active Directory Configured** (Domain Name as "DOMAINNAME" is configured)

I need to install SQL Server full installation but NOT on Virtual machine. I need it on my local PC. If I do so, would the VM be able to communicate through the SQL Server details? I need the SQL Server Details while configured the Farm Installation in Sharepoint Server 2010.

Let me know for any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xor,

Your VMWare Virtual machine should be using Internet Connection to your host machine, if you are having problem with that - have a look at :
[Troubleshooting networking and internet connection issues in VMware Fusion](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016466)

You can then install SQL Server Management Studio and Client Tools on Virtual Machine to check connection between your machine's SQL Server Instance!

As Sumol has suggested that 1433 default port should be allowed by FireWall of your host machine...

Its more than a try thing as to ask, in short there shouldn't be any problem!!

Comment: Yeah, I shared a folder from host (local) machine and was able to see that from VM machine

Comment: You are all done, SQL Server connection should work!

Comment: I installed SQL on my local PC but the sql instance is not being recognized by Sharepoint when doing farm installation. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1- Make sure you are able to connect SQL Instance from your local PC.. 2- Disable the Firewall for your local PC as well as VM... 3- Try pinging the IP of your local PC from VM

Comment: 1- is it necessary to connect to SQL Instance using SQL Server Authentication? I'm able to connect using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Windows Authentication is good, but is your local machine is domain controller? If not, are you using the same user to connect VM?

Comment: I dont think my machine is domain controller.does it have to be in same domain name as that of VM? I didn't get the second question :-)

Comment: Just make sure they are using same credentials... If domain exists then same domain user!

Comment: I was not able to PING my local machine from the VMWare Virtual machine. Because of n/w connectivity the sql instance is not being setup

Comment: Arsalan: Your inputs would be much appreciated

Comment: Fix up the network somehow, try reaching the VMWare guides on network... I already shared the link with you!

Comment: I have installed db in virtual machine - sweet and easy

Answer (score 1):

If you install SQL on your local machine and SharePoint on your virtual machine it should work without a problem as long the can access the same network.

Make sure that at least the following is true:

1. Both machines are in the same domain and you can login to the machines using the SharePoint administrator account
2. On the SQL machine make sure the port 1433 is open (this could be different if you are not using the default port)

When going through the SharePoint installation you should be able to connect to the SQL.

Comment: Thanks. With ref to my question, does that mean that my local PC should be under DOMAINNAME domain?

Answer (score 0):

It will of course depend on what Virtualization software you use (Hyper-V, VM-Ware, etc.) as each one is configure differently. Beyond that, assuming your target is to simply communicate between host-client, you could simply make a private network between host-client - most virtualization software allow that.

With Hyper-V have a look at various types here http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/06/17/hyper-v-what-are-the-uses-for-different-types-of-virtual-networks.aspx and detailed steps here http://ramazancan.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/hyper-v-r2-networking%E2%80%93-how-to-configure-management-vm-networks/

Comment: I'm using VM-Ware.